# How safe using combobox to input foreign key

Tags: ms-access, combobox, foreign-keys

In a Related Tables, you need to enter a FK to link to the parent table.
You either key in the FG from memory !!!!!! or use help.
The standard procedure is to design the field as combo box AND use SQL to select the field that will help to input the ID of the parent table. So, if you want to input foreign key 3 , the combo box will display what 3 is then when you selected Access will insert 3 for you.

My question is since I can later on, edit the table and change the the value to another value, and mess the whole thing up!!! HOW can I lock my first choice so it will stay unedited ?

My second question is: Is this the only way to input the FK if you do not remember the exact ID number or there are thousands of records in the parent table.?

Answer (score 0):

Re. #1

In Access 2010 you could use a trigger to check whether the value has been used in another table as a FK and not allow the change. In previous versions all you could do, would be to hide the navigation pane or make the table hidden.

Re. #2

You could use a `listbox` (basically the same idea as a `combobox`).
You could include the lookup table in the underlying query, but then there is more danger of the values getting changed, which is exactly what you were worried about in the first question.

Stick with the `combobox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different versions of a form. One might have `Allow Edits, No`, another might be `Data Entry, Yes`, meaning that it can only be used to create new records.

However, suppose someone is creating a new record and they select the wrong FK by mistake. How can they correct this? You could use VBA to produce a confirmation dialog in the first instance, and perhaps an Undo button where VBA would deliberately perform the Undo. Access 2010 also has Data Macros (equivalent to triggers) that you might use to store the old and new values, and other information, when a user changes a FK value.

Access does not implement user-level security, so the user can still open and change data in the raw-data tables. You should, however, have *enforced referential integrity* on the table-join, so that a user cannot enter a FK that doesn't already exist as a PK in the related table.

In summary, you could add additional columns to the combobox to help the user select the correct item, and you might consider an additional confirmation dialog (a MsgBox) before a record is saved into the data-table. But **you cannot prevent people from making mistakes**. (Enforcing Referential Integrity will prevent nonsense data from being entered.)

Second question:
A combobox (or possibly a listbox) is the easiest way for users to enter a FK value, without relying on memory. An alternative would be to use a button (or other control and event) that opens a secondary form. This form might have some filtering features to help the user find the correct FK value. When this form is closed you would then need to write some code to update the relevant control on the main form.